# Asp net core tasks like rails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Comming from Rails word to Asp net core. There are command line tasks (commands) available in the Rails that you can create. These command can be run manually or from Cron. It is possible to use model classes and next parts of the application in the task.

Is it possible to create tasks in the Asp net core word?

Answer (score 1):

There is no the same tasks funcionality in dotnet core, but if you need to execute code from Cron, have some options:

- Create an action and invoke it by CURL or Web-Request;
- Create another project (Console application), to [make a new dotnet
  verb](http://mattwarren.org/2016/10/03/Adding-a-verb-to-the-dotnet-CLI-tooling/) and reference your project DLL.

You can also [open an issue](http://mattwarren.org/2016/10/03/Adding-a-verb-to-the-dotnet-CLI-tooling/) suggesting this feature.